# Maven - How to get a list of repositories a build is going to use without building it

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I checked out a project at work on a new linux install.  When I go to build it, it's trying to pull dependencies from from external repositories that are not in the project pom or the parent pom, mainly "repository.jboss.org"
Here is the bizarre thing.  If i pull another project it tries the same thing.
Other members of the team can build it with a clean checkout and local repository without issue and it doesn't try to resolve the external repository.

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```

doesn't have it listed anywhere.

i tried the:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.9:list-repositories
```

but that fails to build because it can't a dependency it needs from from a repository its trying to reach.

the pom in the mvn install hasn't been touched.

is there some command that I can run that will show where its going to try to and resolve dependencies from and why that DOES NOT require it to build, so that I can try to hunt down where these are coming from?

Thanks

UPDATE:
I noticed that on the machines it built on, the mvn version 3.2.1 was being used.  I was using 3.2.3.  when I went to download 3.2.1 i noticed 3.2.5 was out.  I downloaded both 3.2.1 and 3.2.5.  3.2.5 failed but it built with 3.2.1, although it was still trying to get things from from a repository not in my build plan, it eventually worked ~ weird.  So i got to do `list-repositories`.  Below are the ones listed besides the internal ones that should be used.

3.2.5 & 3.2.1

```
[INFO] Repositories Used by this build:
[INFO]        id: apache.snapshots
      url: http://repository.apache.org/snapshots
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => never]
 releases: [enabled => false, update => daily]

[INFO]        id: codehaus.snapshots
      url: http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => daily]
 releases: [enabled => false, update => daily]

[INFO]        id: snapshots
      url: http://snapshots.maven.codehaus.org/maven2
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => daily]
 releases: [enabled => false, update => daily]
```

It doesn't include the for mentioned repository its trying and failing at.  BTW, the items it tries to get from repository.jboss.org, when I load it in the browser is a 404.

I'm guessing something changed in the maven that either fixed a bug we were exploiting or the opposite.

Comment: Check the `settings.xml` files? Be sure to check both the global and user `settings` files. In any case, you (and everyone in your team) should be using the same `settings.xml` configuration.

Comment: Is that repository listed in any pom files anywhere in the dependency tree?

Comment: To answer your question, try this: `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.9:list-repositories`. If it's what you are after really, I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: we're all using the same settings.xml, and I should have mentioned the I used the list-repositories option.  but it fails because it can't build because it can't a dependency from a repository.  will update question.

Comment: @RobinMasters, don't check out any project - just a create a simple maven project using your IDE and see if the "jboss" repository is listed in that too using `list-repositories`. This will tell you if the `settings.xml` is the culprit. If it's not listed, it could be listed in one or more of the POM's of the dependencies in the dependency tree.